# "test -v $TESTENV" always false, even when TESTENV is defined

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I'm running Bash 4.4.19, under Fedora 27, and I have a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TESTENV="Hello"
echo "$TESTENV"
if [ -v $TESTENV ]; then
    echo "Yup"
fi
echo "Done"
```

When I run this, it prints:

```
Hello
./myscript: line 3: [: Hello: binary operator expected
Done
```

So, I add the extra bracket to line 3, which now looks like:

```
if [[ -v $TESTENV ]]; then
```

But produces:

```
Hello
Done
```

**What gives?** I expected to see "Yup" for one/both of the above. I've tried wrapping `"$TESTENV"` in quotes, and I've also tried the `-z` operator instead - but *the behavior is the same.*

Comment: Re: "tried the `-z` operator instead" -- Why would you expect `[ -z Hello ]` to ever be true? It's false by definition. And when your variable *isn't* set, without quotes on the expansion, `[ -z ]` is equivalent to `[ -n "-z" ]`, which is true (as `-n` is the default operation of test when given only a single operand). If you wanted `-z` to be helpful, you need more quotes: `[ -z "$TESTENV" ]`, so you can get `[ -z '' ]` invoked if the variable is empty.

Comment: ...this is a place where enabling logging with `set -x` would have made the issue immediately obvious.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, I've never used `set -x` before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `$`, you are using the *value* of the variable, not the variable name itself. You probably meant:

```
if [[ -v TESTENV ]]; then
    echo "Yup"
fi
```

---

If you defined variable named `Hello` (such as `Hello=hi`) the `if` condition would have succeeded and you might not have noticed the problem at all :)

Comment: If you're going to assume `-v` is implemented, you may as well use `[[` instead of `[`.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant - I missed that in every reference/tutorial I compared my script to.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to test if a variable exists and is not null :

```
if [[ $TESTENV ]]; then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but I think the most important was not answered. The single bracket `[` is actually an alias for the `test` command. This means that `[` is *not* a syntax.

Therefore, when `[` has one or more of the operands that is trying to evaluate return an empty string, it will complain that it was expecting two operands (binary) (*"missing operand"* issue). This is why you see developers doing `[ x$foox = x$blahx ]`, the `xx` guarantees that the operand will never evaluate to an empty string.

The double bracket `[[ ]]`, on the other hand, *is a syntax* and is much more capable than `[ ]`. However, it is important to note that `[[ ]]` is not supported by all POSIX shells. Also, it does not have the *"missing operand"* issue, and it allows for more C-like syntax with `>, <, >=, <=, !=, ==, &&, ||` operators.

My recommendation is the following: If your interpreter is `#!/bin/bash`, then use `[[` but if you want portability use `[`.

So in this case a POSIX compatible option will be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
TESTENV="Hello"
echo "$TESTENV"
if [ -v TESTENV ]; then
    echo "Yup"
fi
echo "Done"
```